# Java jar file load error Error: Could not find or load main class Something.class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Something.class

Tags: java, executable-jar

The Main class runs when it is not in a jar file.  It is not part of any package.  When I try to make a jar file to encapsulate it and all libraries that support the file using:

```
jar -cvf Something.jar src\*.class
```

and then try to run it using:

```
java -jar Something.jar
```

I get the following, even though the verbose messages show 'added manifest'.

```
no main manifest attribute, in Something.jar.
```

If I look at the manifest it created I get:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 13.0.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)
```

but no Main-Class: Something.class statement.

If I add the entry point for the jar file:

```
jar -cvef src\Something.class Something.jar src\*.class
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src\Something.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src\Something.class
```

I get the same result using:

```
jar -cvef Something.class Something.jar src\*.class
```

I see the entry point has been added because expansion of the jar file shows the following in the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 13.0.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)
Main-Class: Something.class
```

The following is the start class for the whole project.

```
public class Something {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IDiffPresenter presenter = new DiffPresenter();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `Main-Class` should be just `Something`, not `Something.class`. It's the name of the class, not the name of the file containing the class.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a terribly helpful description of what happens. It doesn't help that we don't know what `Something` looks like, either... is it in a package? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: **(1)** `src\ ` looks like a package `src`. Compile inside src. **(2)** `src\*.class` looks like no package statement in the java sources. **(3)** `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` must have a `Main-Class: Something`; can be done automatically by a maven jar plugin.

Comment: check the content of JAR file (`jar -tf Something.jar`)  it must have `Something.class` in root *folder* and `MANIFEST.MF` in `META-INF`. The manifest file must have an entry `Main-Class: Something` (without  src nor .class)  - assuming there is no `package` statement in `Something.java`

Comment: src\ isn't a package, its a folder within a project along with dist\, lib\, and build\.  I'm not using maven since I don't have permissions on this machine to add it.  Nor do I have permissions to use ant either.  I'm having to work with just the bare bones.  javac and notepad.  Also it doesn't work aka: Error: Could not find or load main class src\Something
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src\Something.  Same as before.

Comment: `cd src`; `javac *.java`; `jar -cef Something Something.jar *.class` ((if you use something like `jar -cef x x.jar src\*.class` the .class files are added in folder `src`, which is then used as a package {actually Java will only search classes with `package src;` inside the src folder; classes without it, in the root folder of the JAR}))

Comment: Just so I understand, your computer came with Java, or you have installed it yourself? But you don't have permissions to download an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ which would _include_ Maven? Other that this, `IDiffPresenter` and `DiffPresenter` interfaces/classes ought to be shown (or removed) as part of a [mcve]

Comment: No, my computer came as a locked down to the nth degree PC from draconian company with certain governmental ties.  It didn't have a compiler.  They found out I could program, but I wasn't given the tools to do it.  I had to beg just to get the javac compiler.  I don't have an IDE, or revision control, or anything like that.  Besides, it turned out to be a pathing issue, cause among other things, classpath is constantly nuked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was initially overlooked.

`cd src` was the key ingredient.

```
javac Something.java
jar -cvef Something Something.jar  *.class
java -jar Something.jar
```

Thanks to user16320675 for the answer.  All I could do was upvote your comment.